# Recommendations for handling source code inhouse

Tags: version-control, repository

Hi
I'm currently seeing a need for handling source code for a few projects I'm working on. I have no need for external hosting, but I do need to have a structure internal in my development environment.
So, how would you guys recommend to handle this? To you just place the files on a file share in your environment, or do you set up some kind of versioning systems? I'm quite new to this, but I would like to have some way of getting back to old versions of my code, I would like to have the source code centrally stored so I can reach if from bothmy laptop and workstation.

/Andy.l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a source control management system - I would suggest using a distributed one such as [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), so you don't need a server or need to be online to work.

You can still have a central location where you push and pull stuff from if you really want to.

If you *must* have a server, go with [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) - it is easy to setup and widely used.

With all of these options, there are hosted services that you can use as a central store.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use a version control system, it will allow you to do some nice workflows on your coding day and have all securely stored. There are several good free vcs (git, mercurial, subversion, etc). For Some time I used a combination of git + dropbox or sugar sync to back up and share my repos

http://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows OS, then [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) is quite good. You can install it on the server and use a client like [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) to connect to it from other machines. The basic version is free to use.

Answer (score 0):

Do setup a source control repository. Using a SCM, has nothing but benefits.

With respect of what SCM system to chose, to very simple repositories to setup and learn are Mercurial (distributed), and Subversion (centralized). I know you said you wanted centralized access to your sources, but keep in mind that that doesn't meant you can't use Mercurial for that purpose.

[Here's a great tutorial on Mercurial](http://hginit.com) by Joel Spolsky.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of choices based on environment, etc.

SVN is an excellent all-around choice for centralized source control.  You can also use Mercurial and Git internally if you prefer DVCS (even in a local environment).

In any case, regardless of what version control system you have - get one.  Even if it's just one developer doing personal projects, source control is a must.

Answer (score 0):

There's no question that setting up a SCM makes sense and has only advantages. Which SCM to use depends on several circumstances:

- Do your co-workers already know any SCM? We're using SVN and I think it would be quite hard to teach my colleagues the concepts of a DVCS like git
- In my opinion, using a DVCS like git needs more discipline during work: you have to remember to push to the central repository.
- But this is also an advantage: you can create your own development branches and work on them without publishing them to the rest of your colleagues (saves reputation in some cases :-))
- If you or your co-workers often work from remote, using a DVCS is more comfortable than using a centralized one like SVN: you need no connection to your central repository but can still checkin, create branches and (quite important) view the complete history of your project without connecting (e.g. via VPN) to your servers at work.
- For a centralized VCS, I can recommend SVN (setup as [Hps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358899/recommendations-for-handling-source-code-inhouse/4358938#4358938) supposed)
- As DVCS I can recommend Git ([msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) with [tortoisegit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/))
- If you decide to use SVN, you can still use [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) on the clients: the repository is being run with SVN, but anyhow, you get the advantages of a DVCS while being offline.